# java - SimpleDateFormat does not update time

Tags: java

I was trying to make a class (DateTime) where i gather all the method related to formating time, waiting and such. When I'm trying to use SimpleDateFormat it keep returning (init) time, instead of new time everytime i call the methods.

```java
public class DateTime {
    static String logtimeformat = DateTime.formatCurrentDate("HH:mm:ss  ");
    static String filenametimeformat = DateTime.formatCurrentDate("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
    static String picturenameformat = DateTime.formatCurrentDate("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-SSS");

    public static String formatLogTime() {
        String formated = DateTime.formatCurrentDate(logtimeformat);
        return formated;
    }

    public static String formatPicName() {
        String formated = DateTime.formatCurrentDate(picturenameformat);
        return formated;
    }

    public static String formatCurrentDate (String format) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        String formateddate = dateformat.format(new Date());
        return formateddate;
    }
}
```

And where i call it

```java
public class Screenshot {
    static Integer n = 1;
    public static void take() {
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getInstance();
        TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)driver);
        File srcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File destFile=null;
        n++;
        try {
            destFile=new File("/Users/me/Desktop/folder bez nazwy/"+DateTime.formatPicName()+".jpg");
            FileHandler.copy(srcFile, destFile);
            String destfilestr = destFile.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("Created screenshot at: "+destfilestr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong with copying file at destination. Kindly check Screenshot -> take method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect output to be current time everytime i call 
DateTime.formatLogTime
DateTime.formatPicName

meanwhile it keep showing the init time everytime i launch it

Comment: a SimpleDAteFormat doesn't alter the time, it just changes the way it is presented to you.

Comment: You wrote: _it keep showing the init time everytime i launch it_ It's not clear to me from the code you posted. What is _init time_ ?

Comment: init time as in time from when i launch the program, not from when i call the methods specificly in code

Comment: static means the values are set when the class is first loaded, and kept like that.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions. Variable names are written in camelCase, that means they start with lowercase. — **Edit**: That's better. ;-)

Comment: Furthermore, you should not use the `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes, since they are obsolete. You should definitely try the newer Java Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect. Change this:

```
static String logtimeformat = DateTime.formatCurrentDate("HH:mm:ss  ");
static String filenametimeformat = DateTime.formatCurrentDate("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
static String picturenameformat = DateTime.formatCurrentDate("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-SSS");
```

to this:

```
static String logtimeformat = "HH:mm:ss";
static String filenametimeformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss";
static String picturenameformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-SSS";
```

Comment: Good catch. You might as well mention what the values of `logtimeformat`, `filenametimeformat` and `picturenameformat` are upon class loading.